# Angularjs problems with $anchorscroll and webapps

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app

Has anyone else had issues when creating a chrome webapp ( Save to homescreen ) when they have a view with an anchorscroll.  It works fine when viewed from chrome browser ( desktop or mobile ) but from webapp the app crashes right away.

On another note,  I also notice that in the angular docs their own demo of anchorscrolling does not work.  http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/docs/api/ng.$anchorScroll.
If I click on it,  it does not scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Do you see any console output when it crashes? Can you give some demo code?